# Get text between two strings in unix

Tags: sed

i need to get the text between two words or text segments in a string.

I've searched and tried EVERTYHING with sed, and can't get it to work :S

I have a string like "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee" and i want to extract the text between, let's say, bbb and ddd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `bbb` doesn't occur after the text you are interested in, and the reverse constraint for `ddd`, you can do it like this:

```
 sed 's/^.*bbb //; s/ddd.*$//' <<< "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee"
```

Output:

```
ccc
```

`sed` is probably not the best tool for this, maybe you could explain a bit more about what you are trying to do? For example you may want to use positive lookbehind and lookahead:

```
grep -oP '(?<=bbb ).*?(?=ddd)' <<< "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee"
```

Output:

```
ccc
```

#### Edit

According to comments the OP wants to extract the ip address from `checkip.dyndns.org`. A generic and more portable way to do that is with `grep -o`, e.g.:

```
curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | grep -oE '([0-9]+.){3}[0-9]+'
```

Comment: `<<< "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee" | grep` syntax did not work on my system (ubuntu, bash4).

Comment: @anishsane: my mistake, it was supposed to be `<<<"..." grep` (no pipe), but your edit is also fine.

Comment: @Thor just noticed that you had the look-around solution. +1 yours, removing mine... well I used `.*?` non-greedy.. but this is not explained very clearly by OP. Your answer is good!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, i'll put the situation:

I want to make a curl to get my ip address from checkip.dyndns.org, but the string from there is "Current IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". I want to extract only the ip number from that string, so i think that sed should be the best option? (Actually, im not expert with unix, so, any advice is welcome :))

That's it! :)

Comment: @user2266881: You should add that information to the question. I've added some information on how to do that, see edit.

Comment: @user2266881: the way to show appreciation around here is to upvote useful answers and accept the best one (if it solves your issue).

Comment: :O Didn't saw this, how can i do that? ("Upvote" the answer and accept it?)

Comment: @user2266881: it's done with the arrow and checkmark beside the question, see [this faq entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for some pictures.

Comment: I clicked the checkmark, the arrows with the numbers said that i need reputation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed groupings. The three pairs of parentheses denote three groupings. \2 on the output side is the content of the second grouping

```
sed 's/\(^.*bbb\)\(.*\)\(ddd.*$\)/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the spaces around the output text between bbb and ddd

`sed 's|^\(.*bbb *\)\(.*\)\( *ddd.*\)$|\2|g'`

Comment: Interesting - I see this and one other answer that both group the REs before and after the target RE even though they don't use them for anything. I wonder why...